# @Autowire is not working in Spring security Custom Authentication provider

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, autowired

We have Spring MVC application. We are trying to integrate the Spring security in it.

We have written our custom authentication provider which will do the work of authentication.

Below is the code for my custom authentication provider.

```
    public class CustomAuthenticationProvider extends DaoAuthenticationProvider {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationService authenticationService;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) {

        CustomAuthenticationToken auth = (CustomAuthenticationToken) authentication;

        String username = String.valueOf(auth.getPrincipal());
        String password = String.valueOf(auth.getCredentials());

        try {

            Users user = new User();
            user.setUsername(username);
            user.setPassword(PasswordUtil.encrypt(password));

            user = authenticationService.validateLogin(user);

            return auth;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Username/Password does not match for " + username);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<? extends Object> authentication) {
        return (CustomAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication));

    }
}
```

Here i am getting NullpointerException on the following line

```
user = authenticationService.validateLogin(user);
```

The authenticationService is not getting autowired in the custom authentication provider. While the same service authenticationService is autowired in the same way in my MVC controller.

Is this because authentication provider is a Spring security component?

Below is a my web.xml

```
    <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring/myApp-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>myApp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/myApp-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myApp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

**Edit 1 :-**

I have added the following lines in my spring security configuration file.

```
<beans:bean id="customAuthenticationProvider" class="com.myApp.security.provider.CustomAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService"/>   
</beans:bean>
```

Please help how to autowire my service classes in the Spring security components?

Comment: Do you have log files that report anything useful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps autowiring postprocessor is not enabled in the root application context (but enabled in the `DispatcherServlet`'s context as a side effect of `<mvc:annotation-driven>` or `<context:component-scan>`).

You can enable it by adding `<context:annotation-config>` to `myApp-security.xml`.

Comment: I tried this but its not working. In fact after adding this line in my myApp-security.xml the app is not even getting deployed.

Comment: @Ashish: Did you also add the corresponding `context` schema definition into xml header?

Comment: if there is no luck, why did u mark this as the correct answer?!

Comment: How it's marked as the correct answer.no luck at all. Downvote to save others time.

Comment: Downvoting as this is not the correct answer, see Rob Winch's answer.

Answer (score 4):

Are you using the `<debug/>` element? If so, try removing to see if it fixes your problem as [SEC-1885](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-1885) prevents `@Autowired` from working when using `<debug/>`.

Comment: gooood !!! I spent 4 hours to figure out why it was not working, and even created this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23437738/autowiring-does-not-work-spring-security-on-appengine-authentication-handler. thanks, Rob!! that was the problem in my case.(i still work with 3.1.0)

Answer (score 3):

I experienced this issue and came to the conclusion that while autowiring was taking place, the spring security was operating with a completely different instance of the classes.  To solve this I imported the security configuration into the spring mvc configuration as below.

This allowed Spring security to share the context with my spring mvc.

```
<import resource="myapp-security.xml" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and fixed it.

The solution is even if u have @Autowired annotation set for Service class.

```
 @Autowired
 private AuthenticationService authenticationService;
```

Removed the bean definition in your dispatcher-servlet.xml and it will work.

```
 <!--
 <beans:bean id="customAuthenticationProvider" class="com.myApp.security.provider.CustomAuthenticationProvider">
 <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService"/>   
 </beans:bean>
 -->
```

and add it in security context file

Answer (score 1):

if you are using Spring MVC then you have to add **both spring-security.xml and dispatcher-servlet.xml in contextConfigLocation**.

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
            /WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to define your CustomAuthenticationProvider as a spring bean (in applicationContext.xml generally or applicationContext-security.xml if you have one)

Comment: C  Thanks for the answer. I have defined my custom authentication provider in spring security xml. Please see I have updated my question. Do I need to do anything else?

Comment: I don't see your AuthenticationService in your bean config file. AuthenticationService must also be defined as a bean. Is your CustomAuthenticationProvider is also autowired where you try to use it ? Because if you instanciate it yourself, spring cannot wrap it in a proxy

Comment: AuthenticationService is not defined in the bean config file as I have used @Service annotation here.

Answer (score 0):

You should use 
You cannot use  because your myApp-security.xml  is creating another ApplicationContext which doesnt see all the autowiring from your context created by myApp-servlet.xml