# Where is hided <context:annotation-config/> in spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, configuration, annotations

To work via annotations in Spring need to define:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context">

    <context:annotation-config/>
</beans>
```

at

> annotation-config.xml

But I created a simplest Spring boot Application (lets say I select lust Web in initialazr)

It works on annotations but there isn't any annotation-config.xml there and nor mentioning of ,
where is hidden?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only need to add `<context:annotation-config />` or `<context:component-scan />` (which implies annotation driven config) when using an [`ApplicationContext`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext.html) implementation that doesn't support annotations out-of-the-box.

When only using XML based configuration you also use one of the XML enabled `ApplicationContext` implementations, generally that would be [`XmlWebApplicationContext`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/support/XmlWebApplicationContext.html). With these you would need to instruct the `ApplicationContext` to enable annotation processing.

When using Java based configuration you generally use an annotation based `ApplicationContext`, default would be [`AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/support/AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.html). Due to its nature of processing Java configuration classes it has annotation processing enabled by default.

Spring Boot uses the latter (it actually uses a specialized subclass for this). Hence you don't need to explicitly enable it.

Comment: Hm, then why is not working in Spring boot app https://stackoverflow.com/a/7024103/1104820

Comment: That link points to an old question which isn't even related to Spring Boot. So in short this comment doesn't make sense.